# PostgreSQL Query: Column Sum for the latest available date of each month

Tags: postgresql

Given a pSQL table which looks like this:

```
date       | data
2015-01-23 | 15
2015-01-23 | 11
2015-02-25 | 15
2015-02-25 | 11
2015-01-25 | 24
2015-01-25 | 2
2015-01-25 | 13
2015-01-29 | 5
2015-02-28 | 12
2015-02-28 | 1
2015-05-15 | 12
2015-05-16 | 1
```

How can I get the sum of data for the last available date of each month?
Example result:

```
date       | data
2015-01-29 | 5
2015-02-28 | 13
2015-05-16 | 1
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT year,month,max(day),sum(data) FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      date_part('year', date)  AS year,
      date_part('month', date) AS month,
      date_part('day', date)   AS day,
      sum(data)                AS tdata
    FROM table a
    GROUP BY date, date_part('year', date), date_part('month', date), date_part('day', date)
    ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, day ASC
  ) dataq
GROUP BY year,month
```

The sum I get from this appears to be wrong.

Comment: Please don't tag with unrelated products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the sums in the inner query, grouping by a single day. Select latest day in month in the outer query:

```
select distinct on (year, month) 
    make_date(year::int, month::int, day::int) as date, 
    data
from (
    select 
        date_part('year', date) as year,
        date_part('month', date) as month,
        date_part('day', date) as day,
        sum(data) as data
    from my_table
    group by date
    ) s
order by year, month, day desc

    date    | data 
------------+------
 2015-01-29 |    5
 2015-02-28 |   13
 2015-05-16 |    1
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need just to remove days that you don't want to sum. For example using `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT year,month,max(day),sum(tdata) tdata FROM
  (
    SELECT
      d,
      date_part('year', d)  AS year,
      date_part('month', d) AS month,
      date_part('day', d)   AS day,
      sum(data)                AS tdata
    FROM tab a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM tab a2
      WHERE date_part('year', a.d) = date_part('year', a2.d) AND
          date_part('month', a.d) = date_part('month', a2.d) AND
          date_part('day', a.d) < date_part('day', a2.d)
    )
    GROUP BY d, date_part('year', d), date_part('month', d), date_part('day', d)
    ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, day ASC
  ) dataq
GROUP BY year,month
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/44155/10)

Comment: Thank you. This works but for some reason it's very slow. It takes about 15 seconds to execute on a table with 500k rows.